# Converting a dictionary of tuple arrays to a CSV

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to convert a dictionary structured like this:

```
{
    'AAA': [ ('col1', 1), ('col2', 2), ('col3', 3) ],
    'BBB': [ ('col2', 1), ('col3', 4) ],
    'CCC': [ ('col4', 7) ]
}
```

...into a csv structured like this:

```
key  col1, col2, col3, col4
AAA  1     2     3
BBB        1     4
CCC                    7
```

To be specific, I don't know what the columns will be named, or which columns will need to be created, until runtime, with the exception of the `key` column, which corresponds directly to the keys. If data isn't supplied for a given column, then it is considered to be empty.

Is there a simple way to do this in Python? I'm trying to avoid excessively re-shuffling the data around into different structures, and all examples I've seen for numpy involves parallel lists. I'm open to using libraries such as numpy and pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a simple way to do what you're asking for without processing your dictionary first.

Python has a csv library: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html but you have to have your data in the right format before using it.  Your best bet is the [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) class which can take a dict as each row.  Your tuples can be easily converted to dicts, so all you need to be able to use this class is to get a list of the fieldnames (column names).

Here is how I printed your info into a csv:

```
from csv import DictWriter

d = { 'AAA': [ ('c1', 1), ('c2', 2), ('c3', 3)],
      'BBB': [ ('c2', 1), ('c3', 4)],
      'CCC': [ ('c4', 7)]
    }

# convert dictionary of tuples into list of dictionaries
# and gather fieldnames at the same time
rows = []
fieldnames = set()
for k in d.keys():
    # a list of (k, v) tuples can be converted to a dict
    # but watch out for duplicate keys!
    tmp = dict(d[k])
    fieldnames.update(tmp.keys())
    tmp['key'] = k
    rows.append(tmp)

# add key to the front of the list, since sets are unordered
# you could sort the fieldnames however you want here
fieldnames = ['key'] + list(fieldnames)                                                                 

# open the file and write the csv
with open('out.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```